# Show random pictures in picture box C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 6 images called image_1, image_2... Now I want to show these pictures in random order in a picture box so I created this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    diceBox.ImageLocation = "images/dice_" + rn.Next(1,6).ToString() + ".png";
    diceBox.Update();
    Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

But this does not work. It only shows 1 of the pictures. I have a feeling it is skipping the "Task.Delay(1000)", how can I fix this?

Comment: `Task.Delay()` is an async call so you'll have to `await` it -- otherwise it's fire and forget just like any other non-awaited asynchronous method.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: That sounds like a good answer. Why did you write it as a comment?

Comment: You will also have to use the `Control.Invoke` method. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just use Thread.Sleep?

Comment: As a note, your code could display the same image multiple times in a run. You might be better to have the images in a list that you can randomly select from and then remove to ensure each image is displayed at least and only once.

Comment: @Crono: Why? Async/Await is not multi-threaded.

Comment: @Thomas the code writing suggests that it's being executed in the main UI thread. Thus, using `Thread.Sleep` will freeze the whole app.

Comment: Also, to expand on what I mentioned earlier. Instead of having your wait here, why not randomly sort your images in a list all at once, then you can manage how and when they are cycled through later.

Comment: Just a side note - calling `rn.Next(1,6)` will only produce values from `1` to `5`. The `6` is an **exclusive** upper bound.

Comment: @Heinzi Using `await` on a delay in the main UI thread will result in the app freezing. The proper way to do this is to have a side thread that will do the delay and post the changes to the UI using a synchronized handler of some sort, be it a call to `Control.Invoke` / `BeginInvoke` or using a `SynchronizationContext` object. Then the app will both allow interaction and update the screen at desired time. **Do NOT update the UI from outside the UI thread!** Here's an example using a UI post handler: https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/

Comment: Add images to an array or list.  Then the random number is the index of the array/list.

Comment: @Crono: Nope, the great thing about `await` is that it does *not* freeze the UI, even when used in the UI thread. It's like a `DoEvents` done right. If you are not convinced, please try it in a little toy application. Add `await Task.Delay(5000)` and see what happens.

Comment: @Heinzi Well look at that, it works... I tried something like that a few years back and when the code failed with a cross thread exception I naturally assumed it was caused by `async` / `await` using multithreading under the rug. I happily stand corrected. This actually might just reconciliate me with these two keywords. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with the code is not the `Task.Delay(1000);`. That's basically instantly creating a task whose result is never looked at, but the code that calls it is instantly moving on. It's not waiting for the task to complete. It's effectively a no-op in this code.

The issue is that, even with the `diceBox.Update()`, the UI doesn't get a chance to actually redraw the control. The `for` loop is keeping the UI from doing any redraws. So the final image that is selected in the `for` loop is the only one displayed because it is only after the loop that the UI can update.

The trick is to use some sort of timer to update control. My favoured choice is using Microsoft's Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-WinForms"). Here's what the code would look like:

```
Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
    .Take(10)
    .ObserveOn(diceBox)
    .Subscribe(fn =>
    {
        diceBox.ImageLocation = String.Format("images/dice_{0}.png", rn.Next(1, 7));
        diceBox.Update();
    });
```

A more standard timer approach would be to do this:

```
var i = 0;
var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s2, e2) =>
{
    diceBox.ImageLocation = String.Format("images/dice_{0}.png", rn.Next(1, 7));
    diceBox.Update();
    if (++i >= 10)
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.Tick -= handler;
        timer.Dispose();
    }
};
timer.Tick += handler;
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Enabled = true;
```

I like the Reactive Extensions approach - it reads nicely from top to bottom. The standard timer approach jumps all over the place, but might be more familiar.

I have tested both approaches and they appear to work fine.